# Can't connect to excel via odbc but no error messages

Tags: php, odbc

When I try this code I don't even get an error message but when I do a `var_dump` I get `bool(false)`. So is there a syntax error preventing the connection?

```
 $conn=odbc_connect('sample_db','','');
 echo odbc_error($conn);
 $sql="SELECT * FROM customers";
 $rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql); 
 echo var_dump($rs);
```

Or maybe I'm just doing it wrong. I'm trying this in PHP 5.2 and a 2008 server.

UPDATE: After using print_r(error_get_last()); it generates this message:

Array ( [type] => 2048 [message] => odbc_connect() [function.odbc-connect]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. Please use the date.timezone setting, the TZ environment variable or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/New_York' for '-4.0/DST' instead [file] => *removed* [line] => 2 )

Can this really prevent the odbc connection?

Comment: Just making sure...`display_errors` is set to `On`, right?

Comment: Darn no its not, this just made this whole process much harder. I'm not the admin of the server unfortunately. Even worse no error logging at all....